# Payment Type Not Changed when Contribution is Edited - Also Affecting Event Registration "Pay Later Option"

Tags: contributions, online-registration, payment-method

On the CIVICRM server I have (5.13.5, WordPress 5.0), we noticed that when you edit a past Contribution's Payment Method (ie. Cash, Check, Credit Card etc), while CIVICRM will do the necessary debit/credit to account for the change in the Payment Details, the change in the Payment Method is not reflected in the overall Contribution.  The Contribution's Payment Method is still reflecting the original Payment Method even after the edit.

For example, if i have a Contribution of $10 which was mistakenly entered as Check for payment method, it will record as $10 Check.  When this contribution is edited to change it to $10 Cash, the payment details will record correctly that:

$10 Check

-$10 Check

$10 Cash

but the Payment Method still remains as Check.  This affects the reporting of the contribution as it doens't turn up under the latest Payment Method after edit.  Would this be a bug? Thanks.

Comment: We also discovered a later observation that seems to be related to the earlier post.  There is a online registration of a payable event and the option of Pay Later was chosen, this would create an associated Contribution Record which Payment Method was set to Cash.  However, the subsequent payment using say Check and was duly recorded ended up the same as above: ie. Payment details would record the correct Payment Method, but the overall Payment Method for the Contribution is still wrongly reflecting Cash.

Comment: After looking around, apparantly this issue came up some time ago https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/306   now I think it is affecting Pay Later option in Event Registration.